# IIS 7 websites share same Application Pool

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET app. I plan to run several instances of this app on the same server.

Each instance has its own domain, like www.app1.com and www.app2.com.

Each app instance has its own Admin area, that should be SSL protected. You can't install multiple SSL certs on the same machine and port number, so using https://www.app1.com/admin and https://www.app2.com/admin is a no-go.

I would then like to do the following:

Use my appname domain: www.appname.com with an SSL cert, and add an Application to that website in IIS for each client domain I have:

https://www.appname.com/app1/admin & https://www.appname.com/app2/admin.

But that would isolate session state between www.app1.com and https://www.appname.com/app1/admin - even though, they use the same Application Pool in IIS 7.

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

One way I've seen to share session state across different ASP.NET applications is to use one of the other options for storing session state information. Unfortunately I don't have access to IIS 7 at the moment, but assuming it is similar, here's how you configure it in IIS 6:

- IIS Management Console
- Bring up properties for the applicable virtual directory
- ASP.NET tab -> Edit Configuration
- State Management tab

The "Session state mode" defaults to InProc, but you can change it for your various application "instances" to use the same SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple SSL certificates on the same machine, they just need dedicated IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, you don't necessarily need multiple IPs on your server to install multiple domain SSL certificates on a Windows Server in IIS 7.  You just need to add them from the command line.

I got a UCC Standard SSL Multiple Domain certificate from GoDaddy and then just added all the domain names I needed to it.  You basically just install it to one of the domains that you want and then share it between the others via the command line.  My guess is that this is *not* a best practice for all situations, but it does solve your problem without *forcing* you to share the secure parts of the app.

Check out this link for directions:

http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html

btw - the admin on each domain name will have to approve it. If the domain names on it ever change, it will invalidate the certificate in all your sites from IIS and all the admins will have to re-authorize the changes.